# Access to read module twin data via Azure IoT Hub's APIs?

Tags: rest, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I'd like to be able to pull an IoT Edge device's module twin via an HTTPS GET request just like the Azure Portal does. In the portal, I see this firing...

`https://my-hub.azure-devices.net/twins/my-device/modules/my-module?api-version=2020-09-30&_=164130947416`

...and returning JSON. I'd like to do the same outside of the portal (like in Postman or something).

Obviously, by being logged in to the portal, I have credentials that permit that.

I've tried creating a Shared Access Signature and using it as a header like so...

`"Authorization": "SharedAccessSignature sr=my-hub.azure-devices.net&sig=...`

...but I get back `ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorizedAccess;Unauthorized`

Am I missing something? Maybe a step where I use that SAS to get some additional credential or something?

Or maybe I can't create a SAS that works with any `device-id`?

In the end, I'd just like to be able to `GET` the reported properties for a module twin from any of my IoT Hub devices. No setting, no subscribing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API you're referring to is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/modules/get-twin?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034). You're doing the right thing, but perhaps your method of creating a Shared Access Signature isn't working. One easy way to create a valid SAS token is by using the [az cli command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=azure-cli-latest#az_iot_hub_generate_sas_token): `az iot hub generate-sas-token -n <iot-hub-name>`. By default it will create a token for the `iothubowner` policy, which should give you access to the module twin.

I used Postman, with the Authorization header as you mentioned to check the twin of my device $edgeHub module:

```
https://<my-iot-hub>.azure-devices.net/twins/<device-id>/modules/$edgeHub?api-version=2020-05-31-preview
```

Comment: I had Postman set up incorrectly. Dropped to `curl` and it all became clear. :)  Thanks for the reply, @matthijs-van-der-veer ... it helped me know that it _should_ work!